# What does it mean when a restaurant is called an institution?

Tags: meaning

Is it meant to be a form of praise? Like x restaurant is an institution in New York.

I rarely hear about a restaurant called an institution.

I looked up the [definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/institution) on Merriam-Webster, but still I could not understand.

Comment: This question has been inappropriately closed. It asks about the usage of a word. The extension of meaning from dictionary definitions is not something to be reasonably expected of a newcomer to the site, who should be encouraged and informed, not dismissed out of hand.

Comment: @Anton still, someone is trying to close the question for the same reason.

Comment: @WeatherVane I don't know how to deal properly and respectfully with that sort of behaviour. Does it merit discussion on meta?

Comment: @Anton I copied some comment dialogue into the question, which is really about usage rather than definition.

Comment: for a restaurant, well established and well patronized

Comment: Can you Post examples of that usage? Either way, it's well understood that an extremely good restaurant; say, one that clearly attracted tourists in its own name, might be considered to be an institution.

Answer (score 16):

If you say, for example,

> Brooklyn Museum is an institution in New York.

this is a statement of fact. But if you say

> Russ & Daughters is an *institution* in New York.

with the emphasis on the word *institution*, it is a declaration about this particular bagel outlet. The page: [The 14 Most Iconic New York City Bars and Restaurants](https://www.bonappetit.com/gallery/iconic-new-yorkrestaurants) says

> Eating a Russ & Daughters bagel isn't just a good idea — it's a bonafide New York City tradition.

Please see [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/institution)

> **institution**
> **c** something or someone firmly associated with a place or thing
> *she has become an institution in the theater*

Comment: The Merriam-Webster definition shared here is exactly what is meant.

Answer (score 9):

The meaning of *institution* is usually something like:

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/institution)
> *institution*:
> a large and important organization, such as a university or bank
> a custom or tradition that has existed for a long time and is accepted as an important part of a particular society:
>
> - the venerable institution of marriage
> - figurative *Mrs Daly is an institution - she's been with the company for 40 years and knows absolutely everyone.*

By extension of meaning of *custom and tradition*, a restaurant that has existed in New York for a long time and whose use has become part of the customs and traditions of society or a particular sub-section of society may be described as one of its *institutions*. Hence, places like Delmonico's (established 1830) and Fraunces Tavern (1719) might be regarded as New York institutions, whereas a newly opened diner in the suburbs is not.

Comment: This explains well the meaning of *institution* in the kind of context in which the OP has probably encountered it, but there could be situations in which comparing a restaurant to an institution would be criticism (this would involve a different sense of *institution*).

Comment: @jsw29 Good point.. Yes sometimes we use the analogy to liken things to institutions such as the workhouse or some penal institution. Then it is not flattering. Let's hope the questioner only encounters the nice restaurants!

Comment: And not to be confused with referring to the food as institutional. That evokes school lunches and sketchy chicken salad.

Comment: The common understanding of the specific phrase "(blank) is an institution" is definitely the one in this answer; that something is long-established in the community, and is generally a compliment (or at least a statement about its age/legacy). If instead you are trying to make a comparison to, say, a *penal institution* or a *mental institution*, you'd probably have to phrase it quite differently to make sure people understood.

Answer (score 0):

I'd contend that this use of *institution* is indeed, as the [Cambridge dictionary says](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/institution), a figurative use. (Merriam-Webster refrains from labeling it as such, perhaps because of a more modern view that the distinction between literal and figurative language modes is [artificial and invalid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literal_and_figurative_language#Reddy_and_contemporary_views).)

But independent of a hierarchy of meanings: Most often (to use a neutral criterion), an *institution* is something that has been **formally established.** This is true for organizations and traditions alike: Marriage is an institution because it is officially established, as opposed to mere friendship.

Now we can understand what the "figurative" use is expressing: This restaurant has a status *as if* it were officially established as part of the city or neighborhood, next to the city hall, the theater and the hospital. The place cannot be imagined without it.